# Is MSMQ obsolescent?

Tags: rabbitmq, msmq

We are designing a distributed .NET application on W2008R2 servers and need to send a low volume of messages to multiple known nodes. We looked at RabbitMQ and liked it, but found that we hardly need any of its numerous features that would justify the additional complexity of a separate product (and let's not forget Erlang). It appears that good old MSMQ would actually satisfy our needs.

In looking around, there are signs that maybe MSMQ is no longer being used that much. Many postings about it are old and there don't appear to be any new books about it on Amazon, etc.

What we like about MSMQ is the fact that it's already part of the OS. However, when embarking on a major new system, is MSMQ really still a viable technology choice?

Comment: There are other alternatives like [ActiveMQ](http://activemq.apache.org/), which appears to be a lot more portable.

Comment: Which language/technology do you use for implement your system? I think you could use directly WCF ( if you use .NET)

Comment: @Gas We are using C# .NET MVC

Comment: As a user of RabbitMQ for the past couple of years I would highly recommend RabbitMQ as a messaging technology (especially over MSMQ)! The 'complexity' that you speak of simply does not exist and whilst you might not need the numerous features now the great thing about RabbitMQ is that it can be used in a very simplistic way. It is also very easy to use from c#.

Comment: The fact that no one has actually answered this question yet is discouraging in itself.

Comment: see https://particular.net/blog/msmq-is-dead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have been using MSMQ with Win Server 2008 and now Win Server 2012. As you said it's part of a system and just works. If you are a Windows guy, use it without fear. It is not obsolete.

Just other frameworks/technologies build on top of mqmq. If you happy with the features, then why would you add an extra dependency on RabitMQ or ActiveMQ, apart from more stuff to learn, and more things to fail?